# How can we pass data from Register component to App.js so that I should retain the typed data in register screen

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can we pass data from `Register` component to App.js ? So that the data typed in the Register component fields should retain even after navigating from Home screen to Register screen. But I am getting below error:

`You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.`

Could someone please advise on how to pass data via context?

CSB link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-sun-rhog82?file=/src/App.js

register.js

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import App from "../App";

const options = [
  { value: "test1@test.com", label: "test1@test.com" },
  { value: "test2@test.com", label: "test2@test.com" },
  { value: "test3@test.com", label: "test3@test.com" }
];

const data = {
  name: "Test one",
  mobile: "234242342",
  email: "test1@test.com",
  notes: "How are you doing ?"
};

const Register = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(data);

  const moveBack = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Lets us Know</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="candiate" /> <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" /> <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <Select isMulti options={options} />
        <br></br>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <hr></hr>
        <button>Submit</button>
        <button onClick={moveBack}>Back</button>
      </form>
      <App sendData={setUserData} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Register;
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/home";
import Register from "./components/register";

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        {/* <Navigation /> */}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/Register" element={<Register />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you share how you intend to use the `sendData` prop in `App`? I don't see you using the `props` of `App` anywhere.

Comment: I have tried using useContext()

Comment: @TobiasS. I have added the usage here.. not sure how to send the data using createContext https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-sun-rhog82?file=/src/components/register.js