# TS2604: JSX element type 'SomeContext' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have seen some questions but none really address this problem when it comes to creating a react context.

**creating the context**

```
export const BookingContext = createContext<BookingContextType>({
  initiateBooking() {},
});
```

**JSX**

```
  const initiateBooking = (flight: Departures) => {
    setBooking(true);
  };
```

```
        <BookingContext value={{ initiateBooking }}>
          <div className="rounded-lg mt-1 overflow-y-auto h-96 found-flights ">
            {foundFlights?.map((foundFlight) => (
              <FoundFlight foundFlight={foundFlight} sortBy={sortBy} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </BookingContext>
```

**Type**

```
export interface BookingContextType {
  initiateBooking: (flight: Departures) => void;
}
```

I however get the error **TS2604: JSX element type 'BookingContext' does not have any construct or call signatures.**

I honestly don`t know wtf that is and I need some help.

Comment: You wrap your app in the context **provider**, not the context itself. So you could try `BookingContext.Provider`. Check the React docs for how to use context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `BookingContext`, use `BookingContext.Provider` in the JSX.

```
<BookingContext.Provider value={{ initiateBooking }}>
  /* ... */
</BookingContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Could you please advise this question >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74333226/how-can-we-pass-data-from-register-component-to-app-js-so-that-i-should-retain-t

Comment: @TobiasS You are doing Gods work . Kudos!